# Load page event in Flex?

Tags: image, apache-flex, load

I'm currently working on this website (http://www.jowannes.com/thomasschoof/flash/LauraBarsby.html) and I created a little gallery. When you press the image it becomes the background of the website. Now this has some problems if the background is white and you look at the other pages again, you can't read the text any more.

I would like it to be when you go back to another page, the background changes to it's original one. So basically I'm looking for the page (component?) load event or something alike, but I can't seem to find it.

`CreationCompleted` doesn't work for this, because when you navigate to it the second time it's already created, this the background doesn't change.

I'm setting the background like this:

Main page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:component="component.*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function changeBackground(bitmapFillObj:BitmapFill):void
            {
                backgroundContainer.backgroundFill = bitmapFillObj;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:BitmapFill id="_bg1" source="@Embed('assets/bg1.jpg')"/>
        <s:BitmapFill id="_bg2" source="@Embed('assets/bg2.jpg')"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:BorderContainer id="backgroundContainer" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundImage="@Embed('assets/bg1.jpg')" borderAlpha="0">

        <component:home/>

    </s:BorderContainer>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Component:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:Button label="click to show bg 1" click="FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.changeBackground(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication._bg1)"/>

<s:Button label="click to show bg 2" click="FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.changeBackground(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication._bg2)"/>
```

I also have the problem that the images become stretched, because I can't set the fillmode NOR can I center them, any ideas for this?

I hope somebody can help me, Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Is the creationcomplete event what you're looking for?

Comment: I think it might be, how do I utilise it? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can add a `creationComplete="function"` handler to your application, in the application MXML declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, you are a lifesaver! :D 
Now I just need to figure out a way to make those images centered and I'm all set :D

Comment: Well it works, but when you navigate to it the second time, it doesn't change the background any more, because it has already been created. :(

Comment: Try adding a `show` handler? I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it with the `change` handler in the `viewstack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: In a `viewstack` you have a handler called `change=`, I just put my method in there and it worked.